# Deleting elements with PHP that contains specific id or classes attribute

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-replace

I have a simple question that i didn't found my answer.

I have this simple html code :

```
<div class="iWantThisElement">
Not Delete this one
</div>
...
<div class="itemx">
Delete This
</div>
...
<span id="xxitemsxx">
Delete This
</span>
...
<div class="delete">
Delete This
</div>
...
<h2 id="deleteThisOneToo">
Delete This
</h2>
...
<div class="Iwantthis">
Not Delete this one
</div>
```

I want to have a rule to delete ALL elements that The **class** or **id** of them contains specific word or words, For top example, i want to delete classes or ids with these words :

**itemx,xxitemsxx,deleteThisOneToo,delete**

So, We can have an array like this :

```
$array = array("item","delete");
```

and if **any** element (Like `h2`,`div`,`span`,etc) that Contains that **id** OR **class** of the array, Must be deleted .

And the output of that html must be this :

```
<div class="iWantThisElement">
Not Delete this one
</div>
...
...
...
...
...
<div class="Iwantthis">
Not Delete this one
</div>
```

I have tried many many codes with preg_replace and patterns but i can't solve it.

How can we do it in php? with best and fastest way ?

Thanks.

Comment: You'd be better of using Javascript to do this. PHP is server side, it's not really meant for this sort of stuff, it's doable, but it won't be pretty.

Comment: @AndreiP. i know i can do that but i need to do it server side.

Comment: Alrighty then, I enjoy some dirty work as much as the next guy. Add some real code and we'll talk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

search `this` in `div` class:

`/<[^<]+class=[^>]+this[^>]+>[^<]+<\/div>/img`

search `this` in `div` id:

`/<[^<]+id=[^>]+this[^>]+>[^<]+<\/div>/img`

finally example for class, id and any tag:

```
$source = "<div..."; // your html markup
$find_word = "this";
$class_pattern = array("/<[^<]+class=[^>]+", "[^>]+>[^<]+<\/[a-z]+>/i");
$id_pattern = array("/<[^<]+id=[^>]+", "[^>]+>[^<]+<\/[a-z]+>/i");
$result = preg_replace($class_pattern[0].$find_word.$class_pattern[1], "", $source);
$result = preg_replace($id_pattern[0].$find_word.$id_pattern[1], "", $result);
```

DEMO:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2f64fae1d6cbaa0efc7e777e653097891a43113d

Comment: Thanks dear, but it's not working, and i thing in the last line, after `first_word` the code may be this ? `$class_pattern[1]`, not the `[0]`

Comment: Oh yes! It's just typo.

Comment: Tnx again, but a problem is that, if now we change `this` to `item` the `span id` not getting deleted . can u fix this one too ?

Comment: Thanks again dear Ruben, Can u check this please ? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0cb6c8d963de154176ee6fe931832e4534a70e16 what's the problem with this code ?

Comment: The code is OK. Your question was about `<tag attr="value">content</tag>`. Now the template is `<tag attr="value"><tag ...`. This is **absolutely** different story. If you want delete folded closures, then you should count parent-children relations and delete whole branches of HTML tree. You need parser. You should have whole html end clean it up just before echoing. This activity is out of closures of your question. Sorry. Good news, you can do it easy with jQuery just after html content loaded.